# How to customize/remove Chrome yellow highlight from search result hash bang

Tags: google-chrome, search, highlighting

So I did a google search, which made me land on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3274875/how-to-get-cookie-expiration-date-creation-date-from-javascript#targetText=Then%20you'll%20know%20the%20expiration%20date.&targetText=If%20you%20are%20using%20Chrome,along%20with%20their%20expiration%20date.).

As you can see, if you are using Chrome, some content matching the `#targetText=xxx` of the hash bang is highlighted:

[image: yellow highlight]

But in the dev tools, it is nowhere to be found in styles definition, not even in User Agent styles.

How can it be disabled/customized?

Is that me or Google just invited itself into all our websites?

Comment: The link in your post doesn't have a hash fragment, and I cannot duplicate the yellow highlight. Does this happen in Incognito mode (where extensions are disabled)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This feature is described by Chrome in the article
[ScrollToTextFragmentEnabled group policy](https://cloud.google.com/docs/chrome-enterprise/policies/?policy=ScrollToTextFragmentEnabled).
It was only recently added to Chrome and may still be evolving.
It is not supported by other browsers except for Microsoft Edge
and other variants of Chromium.

---

Under **Windows**, group policies are specified in the registry at
`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Google\Chrome`.

This specific policy is set by the DWORD value `ScrollToTextFragmentEnabled`
whose value is `0` to disable and `1` to enable.
Tested as working on Chrome version 84.

For the **Mac**, see the [answer by storoj](https://superuser.com/a/1576733/8672).

For **Linux**, Chrome/chromium settings are stored in the `.config` directory in `home`.
This hidden folder can be unhidden in nautilus by pressing
<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> ([link](https://askubuntu.com/a/23621/963426)).

google chrome: `~/.config/google-chrome/Default/Preferences`
chromium: `~/.config/chromium/Default/Preferences`

The preference name is `ScrollToTextFragmentEnabled`. (Not tested by me)

---

Website designers may elect to disable it for their website by including the
HTTP header `Document-Policy: force-load-at-top`.
Unfortunately, users cannot force it on their side, since extensions like
Greasemonkey/Tampermonkey cannot modify received HTTP headers.

---

The
[List of Chromium Command Line Switches](https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/)
by Peter Beverloo lists this command-line switch:

```
--disable-scroll-to-text-fragment : This switch disables the ScrollToTextFragment feature
```

However, under Windows with Chrome version 84 this switch had no effect.

Comment: For testing, here is one [test link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat#:~:text=On%20islands,%20birds%20can%20contribute%20as%20much%20as%2060%25%20of%20a%20cat's%20diet).

Answer (score 4):

Check this [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/chrome/comments/hucpkh/can_scroll_to_text_fragment_be_disabled/fypo71q) thread.

It says that the setting is called `ScrollToTextFragmentEnabled`, and it could be disabled via [Chrome Enterprise Policy](https://cloud.google.com/docs/chrome-enterprise/policies/?policy=ScrollToTextFragmentEnabled).

This worked on Mac:

```
$ defaults write com.google.Chrome ScrollToTextFragmentEnabled -bool false
```

In Windows create `chrome.reg` with contents:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
; chrome version: 84.0.4147.125

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Policies\Google\Chrome]
"ScrollToTextFragmentEnabled"=dword:00000000
```

and then double-click it to apply the changes.

For more examples you can download "Chrome ADM/ADMX Templates" from https://chromeenterprise.google/browser/download/, and check `policy_templates/windows/examples/chrome.reg`

Comment: This worked for me, after restarting Chrome

Comment: It was hard to decide where to award the bounty, because the other answer has comprehensive information for other platforms, but as a Mac user, this is the one that helped me.

Comment: @Nathaniel I added a guidance for Windows users too.