# Disable text highlighting in search results (aka: #:~:text=)

Tags: google-chrome, browser, microsoft-edge, opera, google-search

Many search engines and browsers support highlighting of the matching text in the target web page once you've clicked the link in the search results by appending `#:~:text=` to the url and I'd like to disable this functionality. Do you know how?

Here's an example of such a result:

[image]

And how it looks like when you open it:
[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to customize/remove Chrome yellow highlight from search result hash bang](https://superuser.com/questions/1492482/how-to-customize-remove-chrome-yellow-highlight-from-search-result-hash-bang)

Comment: Google continues to suck more and more as they add stupid features. The quicker they die the better

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This feature is known as [Scroll-To-Text Fragment](https://caniuse.com/url-scroll-to-text-fragment).

It [used to be a flag](https://www.reddit.com/r/chrome/comments/hucpkh/can_scroll_to_text_fragment_be_disabled/) you could set, but now is only an [enterprise policy](https://chromeenterprise.google/policies/?policy=ScrollToTextFragmentEnabled). You might be able to disable it through registry edits in Windows.

For an easier solution, there is an extension to disable this behavior by removing the fragment in the URL: [Disable Google Search Text Highlights](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/disable-google-search-tex/ompocnnmgiaoieoanemepjflbokldhom)

It is also open source and can be found on [Github](https://github.com/everyonesdesign/disable-google-search-text-highlights).

Comment: Do you know of a solution for Firefox browser?

Comment: @tparker Are you seeing this in Firefox? AFAIK Firefox does not even support this feature: https://caniuse.com/url-scroll-to-text-fragment

Comment: Yes, on Firefox 121.0 for iOS, on both an iPhone and an iPad. For example, if I run a Google search for "Year of King Charles's birth", the first hit is to https://www.royal.uk/the-king#:~:text=The%20Prince%20of%20Wales%2C%20eldest,of%20Canterbury%2C%20Dr%20Geoffrey%20Fisher. This page has the first paragraph under "Biography -> Early Life" highlighted. (You may need expand the "Biography" section in order to see that paragraph.) I can't find any way to remove that highlighting except by manually deleting everything after the "#" in the URL.

Comment: @tparker Browsers on iOS like Firefox/Chrome are just reskins of Safari due to Apple's forcing of using their WebKit engine. I'm not familiar with iOS but it looks like you can turn it off in [Experimental WebKit features](https://ios.gadgethacks.com/how-to/your-iphones-safari-app-includes-hidden-feature-every-web-browser-needs-and-no-one-is-talking-about-it-0385203/).

Answer (score 0):

I spend so much time looking to disable googles latest dumb idea I am glad the answer to this one was simple.  Turn off java and DONE..

In a modern browser go to google DOT com.
Click the lock to the left of the URL.
Click site Settings.
Change JavaScript to Block.
Close the setting tab.
Reload the google DOT com

This not only stops the highlighting but it stops google guessing what you want as you type it.

The search results are the same so no harm to me.
If you have bought into googles other ways of tracking and training their AI programs they may not work.

It will be time to let someone else track you.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question...